# copy a value from mysql query if one is empty

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem with a query that sometimes, will have an empty field returned.   I have tried to use CASE and COALESCE but I am likely constructing the query incorrectly.

What I need to do in the results is, if b.user_id returns empty, to copy the value from a.useracctid into b.user_id.   I hope that makes sense???

Here is my query, no matter what I have tried it errors for me.

Thank you for any idea or hints you can provide

```
SELECT b.user_id,a.responsetime,a.latitude,a.longitude,
a.status,a.updatetime,c.address
FROM callouts_response a
LEFT JOIN ldap_user_accounts b on a.useracctid = b.id
LEFT JOIN callouts c on a.calloutid = c.id
WHERE calloutid = :cid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you have used `COALESCE()` but you can do like

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.user_id,a.useracctid) as somecol,
a.responsetime,
a.latitude,
a.longitude,
a.status,
a.updatetime,  
c.address
FROM callouts_response a
LEFT JOIN ldap_user_accounts b on a.useracctid = b.id
LEFT JOIN callouts c on a.calloutid = c.id
WHERE a.calloutid = :cid
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked exactly as I wanted..  I was not using COALESCE correctly in my attempts.. not even close.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT IF(b.user_id IS NULL, a.useracctid, b.user_id), a.responsetime,a.latitude,a.longitude,
a.status,a.updatetime,c.address
FROM callouts_response a
LEFT JOIN ldap_user_accounts b on a.useracctid = b.id
LEFT JOIN callouts c on a.calloutid = c.id
WHERE calloutid = :cid
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well, I hadn't thought of using IF in my attempts, If I could mark both as answers I would.